Rundeck Job Option auto complete
I have a question about rundeck options. I have a job containing a plain text option: name, ip and port. For the option name, a json list is configured containing the names of the servers. Is it possible that when selecting a name from this list, the other ip and port fields are automatically filled in with the value corresponding to the name?

The only way to accomplish this is to use the cascade options as mentioned here. You can use a file with the type file:/path/to/myfile.json. You can find an example in this post.
